# When application load in Chrome Below exception arises : Sometimes Images/ CSS /JS not loading from server

Tags: google-chrome, jsp, tiles, weblogic-10.x

When I load my application in Google chrome , then some images/css are not 
loading in my application . We have recently migrated from Web logic 9.2 to Web logic 10.3.6
It is working fine in all other browsers.

Below are the error logs that it is giving . It is pointing to some specific Jsp page as shown below.

```
  <Error> <HTTP> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1457469713998> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@1098930442[app:SomeApp module:some.war path:/somePattern spec-version:null]] Root cause of ServletException.
    javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException in '/someJsppage.jsp': Input/output error: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
            at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:923)
            at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
            at jsp_servlet.__dclayout._jsp__tag46(__layout.java:1975)
            at jsp_servlet.__dclayout._jspService(__layout.java:646)
            at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:529)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
            at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1063)
            at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
            at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:239)



 <Error> <Kernel><[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1457469714121> <BEA-000802> <ExecuteRequest failed
 java.lang.AssertionError: Reference Count value set below 0, value is-1.
java.lang.AssertionError: Reference Count value set below 0, value is-1
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionContext.sync(ReplicatedSessionContext.java:88)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestImpl.java:2981)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.syncSessions(ServletRequestImpl.java:2959)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestImpl.java:2947)

Edit : This issue is occuring because of the Weblogic 10.3.6.12 ,minor version 12 has issue. Later patch is updated by Oracle WEblogic Team and upgraded to 10.3.6.13 version.After this Issue got resolved.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why a "java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe" will occur?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527795/why-a-java-net-socketexception-broken-pipe-will-occur)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after reaching Oracle Middleware Technology division. WE came to knew that this issue is because of Weblogic .Oracle Weblogic patch is required in order to fix this.